# com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -444, SQLSTATE: 42724

Tags: java, db2

I'm getting below error when calling stored procedure XXXX written in Mainframe DB2. In this stored procedure, we have 'GRAPHIC' & 'LONGGRAPHIC' parameter for which I'm passing "java.sql.CHAR" and "java.sql.VARCHAR" type parameter.

```
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
        Exception while executing Test Case
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call SYSPROC.XXXX(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -444, SQLSTATE: 42724, SQLERRMC: XXXX
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -444, SQLSTATE: 42724, SQLERRMC: XXXX
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.tf.d(tf.java:1396)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jb.l(jb.java:367)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jb.e(jb.java:92)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.w.e(w.java:72)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.cc.h(cc.java:203)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.tf.q(tf.java:1363)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.uf.d(uf.java:2388)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.vf.Z(vf.java:159)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.vf.execute(vf.java:142)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$5.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:906)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:872)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:904)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:113)
    at com.cst.test.common.SPCall.execute(SPCall.java:73)
    at com.cst.test.daoLayer.SPTest.testLogic(SPTest.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
    Failed Test Case Count : 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL code -444 means that the external program called from the stored procedure is not found. Either the name is incorrect, or the program is not linked properly.

More info here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n444.htm

Comment: thanks , this error is resolved . root cause was ==> "If the EXTERNAL_NAME column value is correct, use the MVS linkage editor to create the required MVS load module in one of the MVS load libraries used by your installation for stored procedures."